# Selenium error (DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a test for the site, earlier the script ran without problems, but after some time an error occurred - "***DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist***", which I tried to fix by adding - "***options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")***", after adding I get the error "**chrome not reachable**".. Tried different options, but didn't help.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="/home/adfs_bot/chromedriver",
    options=options
)
driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script1.py", line 22, in <module>
    options=options
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_script1.py", line 22, in <module>
    options=options
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/<usr>/my_script/venvADFSBot/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

**Google Chrome Version:** 106.0.5249.119
**ChromeDriver Version:**  106.0.5249.61
**OS:** CentOS 8 (RedHat)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Take command:

> google-chrome --headless

The response will include a description of the problem, in my case it was:

> [1107/164427.276365:ERROR:filesystem_posix.cc(63)] mkdir /tmp/Crashpad/new: Permission denied (13)

I used the following command to solve:

> sudo chmod -R 777 /tmp/Crashpad/new/